# boot problem after de-installing Budgie

Tags: boot, gnome, budgie

I am newbie to Ubuntu and Linux, and as many I fall prey of various experiments. Recently I installed Budgie Desktop, and after that I uninstalled it. All was OK, but some remnants of Budgie (screen during boot) remained. I installed it again and after that uninstalled. After re-boot my system started loading and reached the message:

> Ubuntu 21.10 tty1  nummatus login:

When I write login and password, I receive some message (not remember now) and that's all.
Could you suggest anything helpful that I should do in that situation?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1378653/edit) to post the error message. Otherwise we really cannot help. It might be less time consuming to reinstall Ubuntu (you can use the live session to backup important data, if you already have not).

Comment: Since you are new to Ubuntu, it may be more prudent to reinstall. You should also be aware that changing desktop environments on an installed system is not a task for someone who is unfamiliar with finding and fixing problems. It's a very messy task. This is why most distros, including Ubuntu come in several versions with different desktop environments. In Ubuntu these are called flavours. The point is that you are supposed to install the flavour that has the DE you want.  You can always "Try Ubuntu" from installation media without affecting your installed system.

Comment: If you want to continue and try to rescue this installation, we will need more detailed information. We need to know the exact verbatim errors you are getting as well as the steps needed to reproduce each error.